# Indicator of loading

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick

I am working on a project that requires a sound to play when a link is clicked. Everything works fine, I used the Javascript below. The problem is that it takes about 30 seconds (depending on internet speed) before you actually hear the file because the browser has to download it. Is there a way to adapt the code below to display an indicator that the file is loading?

```
<bgsound id="sound">
<script>
function PlaySound(url) {
  document.all.sound.src = url;
}
</script>
```

and this on as the link:

```
<a href="#" onClick="PlaySound('/Lang/sounds/<?php echo $pid ?>A.wav')">Play</a>
```

Comment: Like, a loading spinning thing?

Comment: @Jcubed, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forewarning that "bgsound" is proprietary to Internet Explorer, as far as I know. Having said that, you can subscribe to its "readystatechage" event to find out when it's done loading.... (untested! as I don't have IE)

```
<div id="soundLoading" style="display: none;"><img src="someani.gif" /></div>
<bgsound id="sound">
<script>
function PlaySound(url) {
  // Setup some loading animation here......
  document.all.soundLoading.style.display = "inline";

  // Add event listener and set the sound source
  sound.onreadystatechange = CheckSoundLoaded;
  document.all.sound.src = url;
}

function CheckSoundLoaded() {
  if(document.all.sound.readyState == 4) {
    // sound is loaded, remove loading animation
    document.all.soundLoading.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

http://www.highdots.com/forums/javascript/finding-when-bgsound-downloads-47830.html

Comment: Could it be possible to change the image of the link? Instead of changing the text 'Play' to the loading image, change the image, say 'Play.gif', to the loading image, then back once completed?

Comment: @Zachary, in theory it could be done but I can't seem to get my above code to function in IE9 at work. The CheckSoundLoaded is just never being called. It appears IE9 now supports the "audio" tag anyway, so I'm thinking going the route of "bgsound" is probably a bad idea. I'd check out some of the other solutions. :)

Comment: I just can't get it to realize once it has finished loading the audio. Think onreadystatechange isn't available for IE9? I would like to stay up to date with the most current browsers, so that would be a problem.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work either, even though the link provided suggests that it should. If you're wanting to work on modern browser, you're going to want to forget about using BGSOUND all together as that's an IE specific tag and doesn't work in Chrome, Opera, etc. The <audio> tag is new for HTML5, but I don't know what kind of x-browser support that has either. You may have to look into a pre-built library that handles audio in browsers?

Answer (score 2):

### Simple

The simplest method is to replace the 'Play' text for the link with 'Loading...':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function PlaySound(url, anchor) {
      anchor.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
      document.all.sound.src = url;
    }
    //]]>
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="PlaySound('/Lang/sounds/<?php echo $pid ?>A.wav', this)">Play</a>
```

Here is a [demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TEFeL/1/).

---

### More Advanced

Another option is to replace the anchor's text with an animated gif:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function PlaySound(url, anchor) {
      anchor.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.fordesigner.com/pic/zip/200916124527437778027.gif"/> Loading...';
      document.all.sound.src = url;
    }
    //]]>
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="PlaySound('/Lang/sounds/<?php echo $pid ?>A.wav', this)">Play</a>
```

Here is an [example JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bx3TA/1/).

Comment: So, would I define the id tag in the text as "anchor" in this example?

Comment: @Zachary Brown `anchor` is the second parameter, in the `onClick` function attached to the anchor (bottom of my example), it is `this`. In this case `this` means "The anchor that was clicked"

Comment: Oh, Ok. I see it now. I like your example because it is simple and straight forward, but could it be modified to change the text after it was loaded. Another question I had, would it be possible to change the image of link link to indicate it was loading, then change it back once it has loaded?